# Input data from constructor and from method

Tags: java, arraylist

Im creating some airplane reservation system. I want to have already saved some users and this is how I made it:

```
 Passengers passenger1 = new Passengers("John", "Slavic", "john@gmail.com", 3000, true);
```

Also I have this to add this `passenger1` in `ArrayList:`

```
ArrayList<Passengers> passengersArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
passengersArrayList.add(passenger1);
```

Then I have one switch case that gives the user the choice to add a new passenger:

```
case 3:
passengersControllerImpl.addNewPassenger();
break;
```

(*I have also other but this one is important for my problem*)

`PassengersControllerImpl` is class and `addNewPassenger` is method, this is how its look like:

```
   public class PassengersControllerImpl implements PassengersController{

    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    final Passengers passengers = new Passengers();

    @Override
    public void addNewPassenger() {

        System.out.println("Creating new passenger!");

        System.out.print("Add name of passenger: ");
        passengers.setName(scanner.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Add last name of passenger: ");
        passengers.setLastName(scanner.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Add email of passenger: ");
        passengers.setEmail(scanner.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Add balance of passenger: ");
        passengers.setBalance(scanner.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Is passenger vip? (true or false): ");
        passengers.setVip(scanner.nextBoolean());

        System.out.println("You added a new passenger!");

        ArrayList<Passengers> passengersList = new ArrayList<>();
        passengersList.add(passengers);

    }
}
```

As you can see the last two lines of code, that is how Im saving passenger when Im creating it while program is running. My problem is, when I run program and manually add passenger with that method, how to  add that new passenger in my already created array list from main method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, I am not really sure with what are you asking, I would pass the already existing ArrayList as an argument to *addNewPassenger()* method.

Here is how I would implement it:

```
case 3:
passengersControllerImpl.addNewPassenger(passengersArrayList);
break;
```

And here, in **PassengersControllerImpl** class:

```
@Override
public void addNewPassenger(ArrayList<Passengers> arr) {
        System.out.println("Creating new passenger!");

        System.out.print("Add name of passenger: ");
        passengers.setName(scanner.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Add last name of passenger: ");
        passengers.setLastName(scanner.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Add email of passenger: ");
        passengers.setEmail(scanner.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Add balance of passenger: ");
        passengers.setBalance(scanner.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Is passenger vip? (true or false): ");
        passengers.setVip(scanner.nextBoolean());

        System.out.println("You added a new passenger!");

        arr.add(passengers);

    }
```

Resulting in a new Passenger added to the original ArrayList passengersArrayList.

Let me know if that helped :)

Comment: You understood well, thats it!

Answer (score 0):

Can you share what you main method looks like?

It looks like a scoping issue. First of all, I'm assuming that

```
ArrayList<Passengers> passengersArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
passengersArrayList.add(passenger1);
```

and

```
case 3:
passengersControllerImpl.addNewPassenger();
break;
```

are in your main method.

In that case, a better solution would be something like this:

```
public class PassengersControllerImpl implements PassengersController{

final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
// Remove, not needed final Passengers passengers = new Passengers();

// Set return type to be Passengers
@Override
public Passengers addNewPassenger() {

    System.out.println("Creating new passenger!");
    Passengers passengers = new Passengers();

    System.out.print("Add name of passenger: ");
    passengers.setName(scanner.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Add last name of passenger: ");
    passengers.setLastName(scanner.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Add email of passenger: ");
    passengers.setEmail(scanner.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Add balance of passenger: ");
    passengers.setBalance(scanner.nextDouble());

    System.out.print("Is passenger vip? (true or false): ");
    passengers.setVip(scanner.nextBoolean());

    System.out.println("You added a new passenger!");

    return passengers;

}
}
```

This way, in your main method, you can call `passengersArrayList.add(passengersControllerImpl.addNewPassenger())`

The problem with your code before was that you were not doing anything with the passenger object. If you set the return type, you can use the class to return the object and add it to the list

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your passengersList in a variable, cause in your approach, the list of passengers only exists for one input and another is create for another input.

You should do something like this:

```java
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    final ArrayList<Passengers> passengersList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void addNewPassenger() {
        final Passengers passengers = new Passengers();

        System.out.println("Creating new passenger!");

        System.out.print("Add name of passenger: ");
        passengers.setName(scanner.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Add last name of passenger: ");
        passengers.setLastName(scanner.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Add email of passenger: ");
        passengers.setEmail(scanner.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Add balance of passenger: ");
        passengers.setBalance(scanner.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Is passenger vip? (true or false): ");
        passengers.setVip(scanner.nextBoolean());

        System.out.println("You added a new passenger!");

        passengersList.add(passengers);

    }
}
```